# Collapsible/Uncollapsible list view Like Word outline view

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, jelly

I know there are a couple of examples out there but I was not able to accomplish what I need. I need get the text from a field and transform it to an outlining view like the one in word. Can this be accomplished? Just anything would help. I need to create this on ServiceNow if you need more info but anything in CSS/Javascript/HTML can be transferred to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word Outline view means outlining a selection : In css we can achieve that as following :

HTML :

```
<div>This is some text to be outlined</div>
```

CSS :

```
::selection {
    color: white;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Not really it. It needs to collapse/uncollapse like the outlining view in word. needs to be triggered though a button maybe and convert the text pretty much like the view I described. how do I get the text (could be a copy and paste from word) and parse it to look pretty much like the view described? Thanks for your response!